# intial class variable with async function result dart

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, async-await

Hello Im working on flutter app using changenotifier for state managment
In fact Im trying to intialize a list with async function result
but I get this error:
`Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of '_Future<dynamic>': type '_Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Location>'`

```
class MapMarker extends ChangeNotifier{

   List<Location> locationsList = [];
   MapMarker(){
     LocationsDatabase.instance.getAllLocations().then((value) => locationsList=value);
   }



   static getAllLocations()  {
    List<Location> a = await LocationsDatabase.instance.getAllLocations();
    return  a
  }



}
```

any ideas how to do that ?

Comment: 1. Your code is invalid; `getAllLocations` is not declared with `async` and therefore cannot use `await`. 2. Your revised version of your question makes less sense than your original question.  That code would not generate the error you describe, and it's now unclear what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Small change on you code

```
class Example {
  Future<List<int>>? abc = null;

  Example() {
    initial();
  }

  initial() async {
    abc = fill();
  }

  static Future<List<int>> fill() async {
    return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      return [1, 2, 3];
    });
    // return [];
  }
}

main() async {
  print((await Example().abc));
}
```

**output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Maper

```
class MapMarker extends ChangeNotifier{

  Future<List<Location>>? locationsList = null;
  MapMarker(){
   initial();
  }
  initial() async {
    locationsList = fill();
  }


  static Future< List<Location>> getAllLocations() async  {
    List<Location> a = await LocationsDatabase.instance.getAllLocations();
    return  a;
  }



}
```

Comment: please take a look of the updates